# how to tell which panel fired the click event

Tags: c#, winforms, events, sender

i have an array of panel controls that are placed in various place programatically in my form. Below you can see that as I loop through and increase `I`, all the panels are registered with the same event handler. This is fine with me, but I cant find a way to tell which panel fired the event, in the event handler code. I tried using `sender`but I cant seem to figure out how to use it. So my question is how can I tell which panel fired the event, in the event handler code

```
     Panels[i].Click += new EventHandler(AllPanels_Click);

  void AllPanels_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //need logic code here!
        }
```

Comment: Can you phrase your question in the form of a question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var panel = sender as Panel;
    if (null != panel)
    {
        if (panel.Name.equals("Panel1"))
        {
             .. ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest you skip the 'is' check and just safe cast 'as' and check for null, as the other answer does.

Answer (score 4):

Cast `sender` to a `Panel` first:

```
void Form1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel clickedPanel = sender as Panel;
    if (clickedPanel != null)
    {
        // do something with clickedPanel
    }
}
```